# sed matching "$" literally without considering it regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I was trying to use $ in the sed -e command and it works , eg:

```bash
sed -e 's/world$/test/g' test.txt
```

the above command will replace "world" at the end of string.

what confused me the following worked literally :

```bash
sed -e 's/${projects.version}/20.0/g' test.txt
```

the above command replaced `${projects.version}`, I don't have any explanation how did the sed match the `$` and didn't expect it to be a special character?

Comment: What this means `world$` is it checks if line ends with world because this is the work of `$` in regex.

Comment: See [POSIX BRE docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_08): "*A <dollar-sign> ( '$' ) shall be an anchor when used as the last character of an entire BRE.*". It is not the last char in your expression.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 replaces the word "world" at end of string. this is why "$" after it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you got this man , nice catch. altough Ed morton answered the same below. not sure who should have the credit :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [the POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) says:

> $
> The <dollar-sign> shall be special when used as an anchor.
>
> A <dollar-sign> ( '$' ) shall be an anchor when used as the last
> character of an entire BRE. The implementation may treat a
> <dollar-sign> as an anchor when used as the last character of a
> subexpression. The <dollar-sign> shall anchor the expression (or
> optionally subexpression) to the end of the string being matched; the
> <dollar-sign> can be said to match the end-of-string following the
> last character.

so when it's not at the end of a BRE, it's just a literal `$` character.

For EREs the 2nd paragraph is a little different:

> A <dollar-sign> ( '$' ) outside a bracket expression shall anchor the
> expression or subexpression it ends to the end of a string; such an
> expression or subexpression can match only a sequence ending at the
> last character of a string. For example, the EREs "ef$" and "(ef$)"
> match "ef" in the string "abcdef", but fail to match in the string
> "cdefab", and the ERE "e$f" is valid, but can never match because the
> 'f' prevents the expression "e$" from matching ending at the last
> character.

Note that last sentence - that means the `$` is NOT treated literally in an ERE when not at the end of a regexp, it just can't match anything.

This is something you should never have to worry about, though, because for clarity if nothing else, you should always make sure you write your regexps to escape any regexp metachar you want treated literally so you shouldn't write:

```
's/$foo/bar/'
```

but write either of these instead:

```
's/\$foo/bar/'
's/[$]foo/bar/'
```

and then none of the semantics mentioned above matter.

The rationale for the difference between the way `$` is handled in BREs vs EREs in this context is explained at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap09.html#tag_21_09_03_08, but basically it's just that the standards were written this way to accommodate the different historical behavior of the way people used `$` in BREs vs EREs.

Thanks to [@M.NejatAydin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13809001/m-nejat-aydin) here on SO and [@oguzismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail) in comp.unix.shell on usenet for helping clarify the rationale.

Comment: _"Actually, you could argue it's undefined behavior since the effect of having a $ at some other place than the end of the regexp isn't actually specified."_: How could that argument hold up in the face of the section _9.3.3 BRE Special Characters_ which says _"A BRE special character has special properties in certain contexts. **Outside those contexts**, or when preceded by a <backslash>, such a character is a BRE that matches the special character itself."_  (emphasis mine).

Comment: After some thought, my understanding is that, _in an ERE_, an unescaped (and outside of a bracket expression) `$` character always anchors. So, if it appears mid-regexp then the behaviour is defined: it never matches (`[...] the ERE "e$f" is valid, but can never match [...]`). The behaviour also is defined _in a BRE_ because of _9.3.3_ (`"Outside those contexts,..."`): it matches itself. Just the concept of anchoring is not the same in a BRE and in a ERE.

Comment: The sentence `"The <dollar-sign> shall be special when used as an anchor."` is identical in both sections (`9.3.3 BRE Special Characters` and `9.4.3 ERE Special Characters`), but I think, the word `anchor` refers to different entities. It refers to `9.3.8 BRE Expression Anchoring` (second clause) in the BRE case, and to `9.4.9 ERE Expression Anchoring` (second clause) in the ERE case. The second clauses of both sections are quite different.

Comment: I think you're right, the `$`-related statements in those 2 sections is the key. Thanks!